# Anchor: Change Localnet to Devnet

Tags: anchor, idl, anchor-program-idl

so we delpoyed our code onto devnet, and now I am wondering how to interact with it. The main problem I have is connecting to the provider.

Code:

```
const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
anchor.setProvider(provider);

const idl: Idl = JSON.parse(
  readFileSync("../idl/BigBazaar_IDL_Devnet.json", "utf-8")
);

console.log(idl);

const programId = new PublicKey(idl.metadata.address);
const program = new anchor.Program(idl, programId);

console.log(program);
console.log(programId);
```

Error:

```
const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'AnchorProvider')
```

This is my Anchor.toml:

```
[features]
seeds = false
[programs.devnet]
big_bazaar = "GSmEMymN8dvQW7TLrVD8SUKmyqxc9EcHSUK4AyonrWat"

[registry]
url = "https://anchor.projectserum.com"

[provider]
cluster = "devnet"
wallet = "/home/ademola/.config/solana/id.json"
#wallet = "/home/nashwaan/.config/solana/id.json"

[scripts]
test = "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/*.ts"
```

Comment: are you trying to run `anchor test` or interact with the program from a frontend?

Comment: @Hi_I'mJohn i am trying to interact on the front end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your frontend try setting up `AnchorProvider` like this:

```
  const { connection } = useConnection()
  const wallet = useAnchorWallet()

  const provider = new anchor.AnchorProvider(connection, wallet, {})
  anchor.setProvider(provider)
```

`useConnection()` and `useAnchorWallet()` are from `@solana/wallet-adapter-react`